# Is it possible to do "mixed" XML Serialization in .net?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

I'm designing some complex classes in VB.net (but you can write your answer in C# if you prefer :P) that contain data which has to be loaded from XML. The obvious solution is, of course, to design a serializable class, so to automate the loading process.

Now, my problem is as follows: the XML structure is fixed, and I can't change it, and it has some nuisances that make it a pain to serialize. Here is an example of a tiny piece of DTD that explains the problem better:

```
<!ELEMENT Relationship ( AttributePairs | AscendCaption | DescendCaption | ErrPreventInsertOrUpdateChild | ErrPreventDeleteParent | ErrPreventUpdateParent |ExtendedProperties |HiddenProperties )* >
<!ATTLIST Relationship 

    CountAggregates CDATA #IMPLIED
    CountReplicates CDATA #IMPLIED
    OnParentUpdate (PreventIfChildren|UpdateChildren) #IMPLIED
    OnParentDelete (PreventIfChildren|DeleteChildren|NullChildrenForeignKey) #IMPLIED
    IsEnforce (True|False) #REQUIRED 
    OnChildInsertOrUpdate (PreventIfNoParent|InsertParentIfNone) #IMPLIED
    ChildRoleName CDATA #IMPLIED
    ParentRoleName CDATA #IMPLIED
    ParentAttributeGroupInstance CDATA #IMPLIED
    ChildAttributeGroupInstance CDATA #IMPLIED

>

<!--Lots of other sutff not needed for this example -->
```

As you can see, all the above attributes could be easily serialized by just declaring the corresponding property and decorating it with the `<XmlAttribute()>` tag.
Except for:

IsEnforce (True|False) #REQUIRED

Since True and False are not valid boolean  values in  xml (due to the capital T and F) and the serialization process will fail.

Now... the only other option that I know is to implement IXMLSerializable by hand, which I have done for other classes, and it works, but it also means I have to read "manually" every attribute/element, even the ones that I could easily serialize automatically with tags.

So, finally, my question: **is it possible to MIX the two methods? Ie: serialize automatically with tags and then "step in" manually and read manually the more "tricky" values? (the boolean just an example, suppose I want to manually read certain properties at will)**

Comment: So you have an XML DTD with illegal values?

Comment: XML is very strict.  If you're "xml" requires invalid xml, then it's not xml... so you'll probably want a pre-processor to handle the issues and keep your *actual* XML manipulation dirt-simple

Comment: @StingyJack: nope, in DTD you can do what you want, and the designers of that DTD (I didn't design it) decided to use True and False. BUT the XSchema standard, which is used for serialization in .NET, is more strict and only allows "true" and "false" as valid booleans.
The problem here is that I already have the XML, and it isn't "incorrect" per se... the point is I have to adapt it to my needs, and in the class I need a boolean, so I must somehow read it as a boolean, even if for the DTD it's just a enumerated attribute

Comment: correct! Given this, why on earth is `true.ToString () == "True"` not `"true"`?..

Comment: @Anton: good question, dunno what they were thinking actually :D In fact, I read someone else protesting about it on the microsoft forums if I remember correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always create `private` field (or with `XmlIgnore`) of type `bool` and then property that will expose it as `True/False` and have a setter that can parse anything like `T/F`, `True/False`, `Y/N`, etc.

For generic case you can create `enum`.

Comment: This is an interesting workaround, thanks for the heads up! Tho it doesn't answer the question of whether or not I can mix tags with IXMLSerializable

Comment: @Master_T i guess no. my suggestion is really cheap and simple. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @Master_T: no, you can't mix them. I use adapter properties or enums too.

Comment: Yep, guess it's the only way. Marked as best answer, since it's the best way around this it seems... thanks!

Comment: Damn, just found out this is useless to me, since apparently XML serialization with tags does not work with Private fields/properties... so having a private property serialize True/False as string and then exposing it through a public boolean property won't work... any idea around this, besides making both properties public?

Comment: No. Make them public or use `DataContractSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

If Andrey's suggestion doesnt work, you could insert a text parser that "fixes" the values before or after the serialization/deserialization operation.

Possible dupe of [XmlSerializer and OnSerializing/OnSerialized alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507147/xmlserializer-and-onserializing-onserialized-alternatives)